# Are there any multiline comments in R?

Tags: r, comments

I am learning R and I would like to know if there are multiline comments in R.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it this: 

if(FALSE) {
...
}

Comment: I would say that strictly speaking, there is no such thing. There are a few things that you can use to act as multi-line comments, however. In the popular R IDE RStudio, you can easily and quickly comment/uncomment multiple lines using CTRL-SHIFT-C. Otherwise, as you mention, you can use an `if (FALSE) { ... }` block, though be aware that what you put within that block still has to be syntactically valid, unfortunately. Finally, you can use a standalone string, though I'm personally not a fan. Lack of a true multi-line comment is one of my less favorite things about R

Comment: thank you very much :)